# Kindle Devices Which Support Two Page Layout

Tags: kindle, fixed-layout

Which kindle devices, exactly, support two page layout spreads and which do not?

Comment: Fixed layout, reflowable, or both?

Comment: Fixed Layout :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All Kindle devices that support fixed layout ebooks (so, the Paperwhite and the various versions of the Fire) should support two page layouts. It's important to note, though, that in the [Kindle Publishing Guidelines](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fkindlegen.s3.amazonaws.com%2FAmazonKindlePublishingGuidelines.pdf&ei=rf4JVOuhLMyzogTv_ILYBg&usg=AFQjCNHCeowXw-ksD1k1v6q69SMCY_-DQA&sig2=IMJNbhJTLwHvFUZewWVb6g&bvm=bv.74649129,d.cGU), the only place that two-page spreads are mentioned is in Section 5: Creating Fixed-Layout Graphic Novels/Manga/Comics. In Section 4: Creating Fixed-Layout Children's Books the only way that page spreads are demonstrated is by making a single html page that looks like two print pages. In other words, if what you want is a book that will display a single page in portrait and two facing pages in landscape, you need to make sure it's a comic rather than a children's book.

Comment: One thing worth noting about this answer is that Amazon just came out with the Kindle Kids' Book Creator which is basically the comic creator with more text support and does support 2 page layouts.  I think this app was directly aimed at resolving the weird way people were having to build kid's books under the guise of graphic novels or manga.  I don't have access to the devices so I take it that all paperwhite and fire models will be able to support the 2 page design which I created with the kid's book creator, yes?

Comment: I can't say for certain, I don't have those devices with me right now and haven't built anything with that software regardless. Your best bet would be to check it in Kindle Previewer until you can find someone who can either lend you the devices or test for you.